# Content Template within an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When I try to include both td definitions in one content template within one UpdatePanel I get the error below:
Error:Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'ctl00_schoolAdmin_UpdatePanelSchoolAddress'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another updatepanel' "

I have had to now split the td into two update panels (as below), is there a way to avoid this?

```
   <tr>
    <td style="width: 180px">
        <!-- Update panel to show School Address Header -->
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSchoolAddressHeader" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="frmSchoolAddressHeader" runat="server" Text="Address" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SchoolLEADropDownList" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FindSchoolIDButton" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
      <!-- Update panel to show School Address Text -->
    <td style="width: 300px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSchoolAddress" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="frmSchoolAddressText" runat="server" Visible="false"> </asp:Label>
                </td>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SchoolLEADropDownList" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FindSchoolIDButton" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole Table in the update panel